# CSS Slider with HTML not working - What to do?

Tags: html, css

Hello my css slider does not work. It should look like this:

[image: Desired Output]

but it looks like that:

[image: Current Output]

I dont know what to change with my css and html.

The full code is here: https://codepen.io/ay-the-reactor/pen/vYBbBVo

I would be really happy if someone could help

Here is some of the Code:

```
<div class="image--box">
    <div class="image-border">
        {* Erstes Bild *}

        {if $sArticle.image}
            <input checked="checked" class="hidden" id="rSlide0" name="gallery2061" type="radio">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li id="slide0"><img src="{$sArticle.image.thumbnails[$bigImageIndex].source}"  alt="{$sArticle.articleName}" title="{$sArticle.articleName}" ></li>

            </ul>

        {/if}
        {* Weitere Bilder *}
        {if $sArticle.images}
            {foreach from=$sArticle.images item=sArticleImage name="imageCounter"}
                {if $smarty.foreach.imageCounter.iteration}
                    <div class="image--outer-frame">
                        <input type="radio" id="image{$smarty.foreach.imageCounter.iteration + 1}" name="cbax-gallery-target">
                        <div class="image--inner-frame">
                            <img class="not--dragable" src="{$sArticleImage.thumbnails[$bigImageIndex].source}"
                                 alt="{$sArticle.articleName}"
                                 title="{$sArticle.articleName}"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
    </div>
    {if $sArticle.images}
        {* Thumbnails *}
        {include file="coolbax/ebay_template/{$theme.templateName}/frontend/thumbs.tpl"}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly update your codepen Code it's not working right now.

Comment: Hello no it is working. The code contains multiple .tpl files. I cannot post all of them so i just posted the part where you can see the slider. You may not see any pictures because it loads them from my online shop.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/p9t9f1
open this link and see how your  codepen output is display.

Comment: I found a way to upload it. Here you can see it: https://www.ebay.de/itm/561035150A-VW-Composition-Color-Radio-Bluetooth-CC-Jetta-Passat-Tiguan-2012-/263579060727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: After seeing your link, try this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
.image--box {
    width: 100% !important;
}}
```

It works in the Chrome inspector.
To remove borders:

```
.image--outer-frame .image--inner-frame img {
    border: none !important;
}
```

For logo issue:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
.product--supplier {
    height: auto;
}}
```

Comment: I found a way to upload it. Here you can see it: https://www.ebay.de/itm/561035150A-VW-Composition-Color-Radio-Bluetooth-CC-Jetta-Passat-Tiguan-2012-/263579060727

Comment: I edited my answer, that code should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you. I added the code to the top of my css but nothing changed :/ Or does it matter where i add your css code?

Comment: It does matter where the code is added. It should come at the end of your CSS. I added the `!important` value to the CSS now, try it.

Comment: I tried it again and i dont know why but still the same. You can check it here: https://www.ebay.de/itm/3Q0035842A-VW-Steuergeraet-Infotainment-SD-CD-/263579079171

Comment: It's because the code you pasted is wrong. You added twice the value of 100% in your code. Please delete the code you added now and paste the one I gave you.

Comment: YESSS it works now thank you very much!! :) But one last mini question. Now I have these things which disturb. Do you know how to remove them or in the case of the right one how to show it properly. https://i.ibb.co/L1vFJCj/Bildschirmfoto-2019-09-23-um-17-48-32.png

Comment: @Autoteile-To-Go Please click the checkmark beside the answer and upvote my answer if it has solved your issue. To remove those borders check the answer again as I edited it.

Comment: Thank you again the borders are gone. I marked the problem as solved. But the Volkswagen Logo on the right is still a bit wrong. Half of the logo is missing.